# Configure context lookup to find JNDI resource environment on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jndi, tomcat8

I have a servlet that has a class that needs to reference a value from Tomcat 8's global JNDI resources.  I have defined the resource in the Tomcat server.xml file as such:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

<Environment name="MAX_LANDMARK_RESULT" value="100000" type="java.lang.Integer" override="false"/>

</GlobalNamingResources>
```

I defined a resource link in the webapp context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/pathname">
    <ResourceLink name="MAX_QUERY" global="MAX_LANDMARK_QUERY" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</Context>
```

I also defined the reference in the servlet web.xml:

```
<resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>MAX_LANDMARK_QUERY</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>java.lang.Integer</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

and I'm trying to reference it in my servlet like this:

```
try {
        Context ct = new InitialContext();
        Context ctx = (Context) ct.lookup("java:comp/env");
        MAX_QUERY_SIZE = (Integer)ctx.lookup("MAX_QUERY");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        MAX_QUERY_SIZE = 99999;
    }
```

I've triple checked how I set up the XML files, and they should be correct, so I'm certain that the issue comes from how I'm defining the `ct.lookup("java:comp/env");` line.  How can I define it so it finds the correct resource instead of throwing a NamingException?

EDIT:
So I have been diving into the debugger and checking my context, and MAX_QUERY is showing up as an inherited resource link that links to MAX_LANDMARK_QUERY.  Should I be doing something special when pulling that resource link so it references MAX_LANDMARK_QUERY in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who is having the same problem, I found a solution.

`<Environment>` should be defined inside the Tomcat context.xml file.  This is the only definition you have to make for the value.

Inside your code, you should call it as such:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
value = (valuetype) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/valueName");
```